# resend function on IRC channel

Tags: irc, server-communication

I am looking to set up an IRC client on a computer with functionality which will give feedback on message receipt.  The connection will be an unreliable connection so ideally, I would like the channel to provide feedback to the user until the message is received by the recipient in a similar fashion that google hang outs does.  In addition the interface needs to be able to run from the linux command line.  I am looking for suggestions on potential IRC clients/methods of setting up such a chat connection.

Thanks,

-akt

Answer (score 0):

IRC (as a protocol) does not support delivery receipts for most messages.

If you are building an application on top of IRC (aka using IRC as the transport protocol), it's possible you could re-implement something like that through special markup in messages (this is what MSN Messenger used, they called it IRCX), but this would not sit well with any pure-IRC users of the network.